# How to properly structure iOS 5 app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, storyboard

I recently started to learn Obj-C, and I try to write my first "bigger" app. 
I want to have application that's structured similarly to Facebook, as in:

1. First thing user sees is login/register screen,
2. if he's logged in correctly, he sees main app screen, which can do many not-so-directly-related things.

I don't know how to structure that app TheRightWay.

First thing that comes to mind is setting subclassed `UINavigationController` as initial view controller, with one segue to 'log in' flow, and second to 'logged in' flow.

But that creates different problem: since (at least from my understanding), I shouldn't use modal segues to transition between different parts of app, would I need to use a chain of `UINaviationController` over and over? That seems like the 'easy way', but I'm pretty sure that's the wrong way.

Comment: I know you can do it as it is object oriented programming but alarm bells always ring when the second line in the documentation for a class states `This class is not intended for subclassing` [UINavigationController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is question is as much about your development workflow as structure.

The structure of iOS applications is tightly coupled with the user-interface - so that should be your starting point.

Since you're using iOS 5, created a story-board - which captures the user interaction through a series of views - is what you do first.

Associated with each view is a ViewController - which is instantiated by the framework as required.  In most cases, the structure of your application is going to hang beneath this.